# ¿Alguien sabe cómo usa el método __cmp__ para comparar los nombres y apellidos de los alumnos?

Tags: python, python-2.7

> Tengo creados dos objetos, ej: Al1= Alumno("Davis", "Díaz) y Al2= Alumno("Jorge", "García"). El enunciado del problema me dice que cree un método de comparación **cmp** para comparar a ambos para más tarde hacer una lista y realizar un orden alfabético

```
class Alumno():
    cont=0
    def __init__(self, nombre, apellido):
        self.nombre = nombre
        self.apellido = apellido
        self.lista_notas = []
    def __str__(self):
        return "El alumno es:  " + self.nombre + " con apellido: " + self.apellido
    def pon_nota (self, nota):
        self.nota = nota
        self.lista_notas.append(self.nota)
        self.cont += 1
        return "Las notas son: " + str(self.lista_notas) + "El número de notas añadidas son: " + str(self.cont)

    def nota_media(self):
        self.suma_notas = sum(self.lista_notas)
        self.media = self.suma_notas/self.cont
        return "El alumno:" + self.nombre + " con apellido: " + self.apellido + " con las notas: " + str(self.lista_notas) + " y una calificación media de: " + str(self.media)

    def __cmp__(self,otro):
```

Comment: Tengo creados dos objetos, ej: Al1= Alumno("Davis", "Díaz) y Al2= Alumno("Jorge", "García"). El enunciado del problema me dice que cree un método de comparación __cmp__ para comparar a ambos para más tarde hacer una lista y realizar un orden alfabético

Comment: Tienes que explicar como haces la comparación: por nota, por nombre, por apellido, por apellido+nombre, .... El método `cmp` debe indicar menor, igual o mayor. Establece el criterio.

Comment: Te lo pongo literalmente del enunciado del problema: " Crea un método cmp_nombre,que permita comparar dos alumnos por su apellido y nombre. Lo usaremos para ordenar una lista de alumnos.

Comment: Sorry, pero no dice "comparar dos alumnos por su apellido y nombre", dice "comparar los nombres"

Comment: Independientemente de la interpretación, me gustaría aprender a usar ese método. Comparando los nombres . Sería alguien tan amable de explicarme cómo puedo implementarlo en mi código. Gracias.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación. Por un lado entiendo que el método mágico cmp se solía usar más con python 2. 

Deduzco entonces que aunque el enunciado del problema( que supongo que estaría pensado para anteriores versiones de Python), podría usarlo. También es interesante el planteamiento que me abres con los métodos eq ,gt, le. Aún no he podido experimentar con ellos, quizás ahora sea una buena oportunidad.

Sobre todo, quiero darte las gracias por la explicación.

Un saludo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método mágico `__cmp__` fue descontinuado con Python 3

Si sólo hay que comparar nombres, la solución es:

```
def __cmp__(self ,otro):
    if  isinstance(otro, Alumno):
        if self.nombre == otro.nombre:
            return 0
        elif self.nombre < otro.nombre:
            return -1
        else:
            return 1
```

El método `__cmp__` debe retornar -1, 0 o 1 según la comparación entre el objeto y `otro` arroje menor `(objeto < otro)`, igual o mayor.

Hay que manejar el caso en donde el `otro` no es un `Alumno`. Probablemente quieras levantar una excepción.

En Python 3 tienes que construir cada una de las comparacíones por separado, pero puedes utilizar el método ya construido, así:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.__cmp__(other) == 0

def __gt__(self, other):
    return self.__cmp__(other) > 0

def __le__(self, other):
    return self.__cmp__(other) < 1
```